Extract flag from .exe file
I have to extract a flag from a test.exe file. The respective flag is run as an argument for the test.exe file => "test.exe FlagName" and in this way I will reach the next flag.
I determined type of test.exe file:
Base address: 00400000
Entry point: 0041200a
MSDOS
Operation system: MS-DOS[8086, 16-bit, EXE]

PE32
Operation system: Windows(95)[I386, 32-bit, Console]
Linker: Microsoft Linker
Language: C#
Library: .NET(v4.0.30319)
Protector: Confuser(1.X)
Protection: Obfuscation(Heuristic)[Modified EP + Strange EP position + Strange sections + Anti-ILDASM + Ctrl flow + Watermark]
Protection: Anti analysis(Heuristic)[Anti-dump]
Packer: Packer detected(Heuristic)[Last section EP + Section 0 ("Ih?|(0") compressed]

IDA Interactive Disassembler, the only information

Output of Ghidra decompiler:
void entry(void)
{
/* WARNING: Could not recover jumptable at 0x0041200a. Too many branches */
/* WARNING: Treating indirect jump as call */
_CorExeMain();
return;
}
undefined __fastcall FUN_00405d00(undefined4 param_1,undefined2 param_2)
{
undefined uVar1;
int in_EAX;
byte in_CF;
*(int *)(in_EAX + -0x2693f8e2) = *(int *)(in_EAX + -0x2693f8e2) + 0x6f + (uint)in_CF;
uVar1 = in(param_2);
return uVar1;
}
Output of Ghidra for each Ghidra decompiled function, assembly lines:
                         //
                         // SECTION.4 
                         // ram:00412000-ram:004121ff
                         //
                         **************************************************************
                         *                POINTER to EXTERNAL FUNCTION                *
                         **************************************************************
                         undefined _CorExeMain()
         undefined         AL:1           <RETURN>
                         0  _CorExeMain  <<not bound>>
                         PTR__CorExeMain_00412000                        XREF[3]:     00400158(*), 00400224(*), 
                                                                                      entry:0041200a  
    00412000 90 88 00 00     addr       MSCOREE.DLL::_CorExeMain
    00412004 00              ??         00h
    00412005 00              ??         00h
    00412006 00              ??         00h
    00412007 00              ??         00h
    00412008 00              ??         00h
    00412009 00              ??         00h
                         **************************************************************
                         *                       THUNK FUNCTION                       *
                         **************************************************************
                         thunk undefined entry()
                           Thunked-Function: MSCOREE.DLL::_CorExeMain
         undefined         AL:1           <RETURN>
                         entry                                           XREF[2]:     Entry Point(*), 004000a8(*)  
    0041200a ff 25 00        JMP        dword ptr [->MSCOREE.DLL::_CorExeMain]
             20 41 00
    00412010 00 00 00        align      align(496)
             00 00 00 
             00 00 00 





                         **************************************************************
                         *                          FUNCTION                          *
                         **************************************************************
                         undefined __fastcall FUN_00405d00(undefined4 param_1, un
         undefined         AL:1           <RETURN>
         undefined4        ECX:4          param_1
         undefined2        DX:2           param_2
                         FUN_00405d00                                    XREF[1]:     Entry Point(*)  
    00405d00 83 90 1e        ADC        dword ptr [EAX + 0xd96c071e],0x6f
             07 6c d9 6f
    00405d07 8e e4           MOV        FS,SP
    00405d09 1f              POP        DS
    00405d0a ec              IN         AL,param_2
    00405d0b cb              RETF
    00405d0c dc              ??         DCh
    00405d0d 05              ??         05h
    00405d0e a3              ??         A3h
    00405d0f b0              ??         B0h

From what I understand, there are 2 options:

Patching the program modifying Assembly code.
Reversing the algorithm.

In both situations I don't understand anything, I need help and solving the problem, to receive the 2nd flag. If it is possible, I would like the solution for both of the 2 options.
Many thanks

The output Library: .NET(v4.0.30319) may indicate that the binary contains .Net byte code. have you tried to load it in a Dot.Net decompiler like IlSpy? IDA and Ghidra may only recognize the native launcher and ignore the attached .Net byte code.

I tried DNsSPy and IlSpy, but the output is more confusing like the output of the Ghidra, as example:
internal class \u200e\u202c\u202d\u206e\u200e\u206c\u200e\u206c\u200d\u200b\u206b\u206f\u206b\u206e\u202b
Maybe the code is protected by some "obfuscated method". Today I read about that, I saw my output :
Protector: Confuser(1.X)
Protection: Obfuscation(Heuristic)[Modified EP + Strange EP position + Strange sections + Anti-ILDASM + Ctrl flow + Watermark]
So...now I am searching about a of how to revert "obfuscated " technique

give link to exe file, you neeed try use x64dbg, and try dump, use ScyllaHide
